# Animating Cursor with Keyframes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a cursor animation with CSS keyframes, but it doesn't seem to work, this is what I have:

```
#video:hover {
animation: mouse_in 1s;
-o-animation: mouse_in 1s;
-ms-animation: mouse_in 1s;
-moz-animation: mouse_in 1s;
-webkit-animation: mouse_in 1s;
}

@keyframes mouse_in {
0% {cursor: pointer;}
20% {cursor: mouse;}
40% {cursor: crosshair;}
60% {cursor: ns-resize;}
80% {cursor: wait;}
100% {cursor: pointer;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mouse_in {
0% {cursor: pointer;}
20% {cursor: mouse;}
40% {cursor: crosshair;}
60% {cursor: ns-resize;}
80% {cursor: wait;}
100% {cursor: pointer;}
}
```

But it doesn't animate when I hover over the `#video` div,

Is there any JavaScript alternative? Or is this fixable?

I had also tried adding all the `animation` styles to just `#video` instead of `#video:hover`

http://jsfiddle.net/pAkbf/

Comment: Provide your ..http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It doesn't work, so it would be useless.

Comment: But I will. Just for your cause.

Comment: So I try to make it work ,but if jsfiddle so it easy to do so!

Answer (score 1):

`cursor` is not an animate-able property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

> Or is this fixable?

Not using CSS3 animations, no.

> Is there any JavaScript alternative?

Of course there is – just set the property (or even better, a `class` or something) on the element(s) whose cursor you want to change in a general time JavaScript animation. (If you don’t know how to do those, then do some research first please.)

Comment: 1+ It's also worth noting that `cursor` isn't transition-able either.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll be sure to do the JS method instead.